# Matlab - intersection coordinates of lines based on their coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have 2 lines coordinates (x1,y1 x2,y2 and x3,y3 x4,y4), how can I calculate the intersection coordinates without plotting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function `polyxpoly` for getting the intersection points.
See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) for documentation and further information.

Here is a short example:

```
start1 = [1;1];
end1 = [3;3];
line1 = [start1, end1];

start2 = [1;3];
end2 = [2;1];
line2 = [start2,end2];

[xi, yi] = polyxpoly(line1(1,:), line1(2,:), line2(1,:), line2(2,:));
```

This will give you the intersection point `xi` and `yi`. 
[image: Intersection]

Note that this function is capable of a lot more than dealing with simple lines, such as boxes, intersection segments, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I do not have the Mapping Toolbox

Answer (score 0):

The intersection point will be (x,y) = ((b1-b)/(1-a1), (a1*b-b1*a)/(a1-a))

where a = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);

a1 = (y3-y4)/(x3-x4);

b = y1 - x1*(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);

b1 = y3 - x3*(y3-y4)/(x3-x4)

You can check the algebra by following these steps:

1) find the equation for the line passing by (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and another equation for the line passing by the other two points;

2) force equality onto the two equations and you will have the intersection point